# Recording a website with PhantomJS and FFMpeg?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ffmpeg, phantomjs, live-streaming

I want to record a website using Phantomjs and use pipeline and FFMpeg to create a live video (Server or Stream URL)

runner.js code :

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 640, height: 480 };

page.open('http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/12-2/', function () {
  setInterval(function() {
    page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: "png" });
  }, 25);
});
```

Commande Line :

```html
$ phantomjs runner.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 24 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 10 -movflags +faststart -b:v 3500k -bufsize 1024k -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/1734882043502131?ds=1&s_l=1&a=AaYJ7cQfH719X5Kl"
```

The problem is that I get this error when I want to start a live stream in facebook:
-In the preview mode is working
[image: In the preview mode is working]
-When I start the Live I got this message
[image: When I start the Live I got this message]

Comment: I tried this :  phantomjs runner.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 25 -t 5  -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart dragonB.mp4 
And i get this error libpng error : Write Error

Comment: You need 30 FPS, and a keyframe every 2 seconds.  Figure out the file issue (name it `.flv`, not `.mp4`), and then worry about the RTMP.

Comment: Maybe speed up it [by using tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)?

Comment: I encountered the same problem. If I get it correctly, setting 30 FPS is by doing "-r 30". How can I change the keyframe ? ffmpeg wasn't clear about that.
In addition, while streaming, ffmpeg shows only ~7 fps - far from the required fps.
I thought it might be related to the number of frames coming from phantomjs, but changing its setInterval didn't show any change.
Any help would be appreciated.
BTW - using obs studio I encountered none of the problems, so I certain my CPU and network are more than fit to the task...

Comment: Did anybody solve this?

Comment: unfortunately no